# Why the size reduce when I convert list to vector?

Tags: r

I have a list of size 500, but when I  vectorize it, I miss of the coordinates of the list and I don't know which one is it.

```
> length(A)
[1] 500

> length(unlist(A))
[1] 499
```

Does anybody has idea what's going wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you post data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have a `NULL` value in the list. This value cannot be present in the vector and is thus removed - causing the length to shrink. See for example:

```
> unlist(list(1,2, NULL, NULL, 5, 6))
[1] 1 2 5 6
```